# Get next row incremental value using insert into values and prepared statement

Tags: c#, db2, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am using a DB2 database and C# prepared statements like so,

```
sql = "INSERT INTO " + LibraryList.INV + ".LOG" +
      "(field1, field2, etc..) " +
      "VALUES(?,?,.., SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by (select NULL) From  " 
      + LibraryList.INV + ".LOG)))";
```

So basically I have my prepared statements I am using, and then I want to insert a value using a select statement to get the next incremental number.. I have used `Row_Number()` to get this in the past but I keep getting errors doing so. This statement yields the error: "Can't find `ROW_NUMBER()`".   What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why not (select count(ID) + 1 from yourTable), if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I have tried that too. I get the error, " Keyword COUNT not expected. Valid tokens: ) ,."   Using:
 "VALUES(?,?,?, select count(LOGID) + 1 From  " + LibraryList.INV + ".LOG)";

Comment: @mustaccio, can you provide example? I am using prepared statements..

Comment: I just realized you have way bigger problems in your statement; its syntax is completely off. Before embedding it in your code, make sure it works when run separately against your database.

Comment: The syntax would only be off at the select statement inside the value. Otherwise it's a working statement. I am just trying to figure out how to increment the value while doing an insert inside the same query, rather than executing two separate queries. Any chance in getting an example from you keeping in mind using prepared statements and I can work from there..  Thanks!

Comment: Check out the @Esperento57 answer below, particularly the "bad idea" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want really do it you can do like this:

```
sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0}.LOG (id, field1, field2) values (values (ifnull((select max(id) from {0}.LOG), 0) +1, '{1}', {2})", LibraryList.INV, stringvaluefield1, numericvaluefield2);
```

SQL generate has this form :

```
INSERT INTO yourlib1.Table1 (id, field1, field2) 
values (ifnull((select max(t1.id) from yourlib1.Table1 t1), 0) +1 , 'value1', 'value2')
```

But its a bad idea. You should use autoincrement on your table because with your solution you can have problems of concurrence if someone try to add rows in same time of you.

if you want insert multiple rows of table2 in table1

```
sql = string.Format("INSERT INTO {0}.Table1 (id, field1, field2) select rownumber() over() + ifnull((select max(t1.id) from {0}.Table1 t1), 0) , t2.field1, t2.field3 from {0}.Table2 t2 ", LibraryList.INV);
```

SQL generate has this form :

```
INSERT INTO yourlib1.Table1 (id, field1, field2) 
select rownumber() over() + ifnull((select max(t1.id) from yourlib1.Table1 t1), 0) , t2.field1, t2.field3 
from yourlib2.Table2 t2
```

Comment: Thanks!! That ifnull function worked great.  I know I don't like the idea of non auto-incremented rows myself. I don't have access to change it, and it's an old db2 database on the 400. So I try to take all safety measures by performing my own optimistic concurrency checks, as well as locking the current function that updates the table.  But I am certainly grateful for your help!